# enable assert during runtime in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, assertions

I tried an [Assert Example](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/use-assertion-in-java.shtml)

it works fine in commandprompt. i run the code using following command.

`java -ea AssertionExample`

but it is not showing Exception while running in netBeans Example described that assertion will work when it enables during runtime So we add `ea`.

How we can enable assertion in netbeans ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Right click on your project > Properties > Run > VM Options
- Add `-ea` in the box

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in IntelliJ?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928534/how-do-i-make-intellij-use-jvm-options-for-all-main-files-in-a-project