# How do I make IntellIJ use JVM options for all main files in a project?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, jvm, native

I can configure a main file to use natives needed, but in my project there are multiple main functions so I need all the files to to use the JVM option when I can choose to debug whichever one I want without having to create a configuration for each one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the configuration under **Defaults** node (**Templates** in the new versions), all the new configurations will inherit its settings. Make sure to change the correct default configuration type, `Application` is most likely what you need.

[image: application]

[Refer to the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/changing-default-run-debug-configurations.html) for details.

Comment: How to change the global VM options? For example, I want to enable `-ea` for all existing and future configurations.

Comment: There is no way to add it to all existing configurations at once.

Comment: Defaults is now called Templates.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: "There is no way to add it to all existing configurations at once" -- is this still the case?

Comment: @awgtek No, you can't add it to the existing configurations.