# How to define default JVM arguments in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm-arguments

Is there an option to define default JVM arguments in IntelliJ IDEA?

For example, I would like to always activate:

- `-ea -Dslf4j.detectLoggerNameMismatch=true`

In Eclipse, the option can be found in:

- Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Edit -> Default VM arguments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928534/how-do-i-make-intellij-use-jvm-options-for-all-main-files-in-a-project

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to do it per run type (Application, JUnit test, etc).

In the "edit configurations" window ("Run" ▸
"Edit Configurations..."), expand the "Defaults" item, select the appropriate run type, and edit its defaults in the left pane.

The full documentation is available [in the IDEA docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html).

Comment: Tnx! Saved me tons of time.

Comment: In the new versions it is called Templates - just for reference :)

Comment: document link was 404ed

Answer (score 4):

You can set your VM options for all applications as a default by picking the application type (for command line Java programs it would be 'Application') under the 'Templates' tree found via the menu items Run/Edit Configurations...  Then all new applications you create will use that default.  Older versions of IntelliJ IDEA labeled that tree 'Defaults'.

Answer (score 2):

This is the field in the Run/Debug Configurations dialog you need to edit:

[image]

Comment: This won't create a default unless you do it under a Template, rather than an individual run configuration.